# HTML/CSS Div Sive Affects Other Divs

Tags: html, css

In this JFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/upmuvk6t/
Why do the .navigationtabs all have the same height? If the inner divs are removed, and the height of one tab is changed it has the same effect, as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/upmuvk6t/

If the parent div's height is changed, it has no effect.

Why is the height of these divs seemingly connected?

```css
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigationtab {
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: 'Baloo Tamma', cursive;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #00ace6;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navigationtab:hover {
  background-color: #0086b3;
}
```

```html
<div style="white-space: nowrap;position: fixed;width: 100%;">
  <div class="navigationtab" style="float:right">
    Account
  </div>
  <div class="navigationtab">
    Home
  </div>
  <div class="navigationtab" style="height:50px;">
    <!--THIS-->
    Services
  </div>
  <div class="navigationtab">
    Another One
  </div>
  <div class="navigationtab">
    About
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `display: table-cell;` is why.

Answer (score 3):

Its because the `divs` are displayed as `table-cell` which is designed to have the same height with other cell(s) in the same row, let's try my answer here - https://jsfiddle.net/upmuvk6t/1/

Modify the `display` value to `inline-block` will solve the problem.
You may also have to add `vertical-align: top;` to `.navigationtab`

### Edit 1 -

I changed the `height` property of `.navigationtab` to `min-height` that would make more sense

Comment: What else did you change? If I modify the original like you said I get this: https://jsfiddle.net/upmuvk6t/3/  edit: Thank you!

Comment: @connor I also changed the height property of .navigationtab to min-height, kindly see edit 1 and this example: https://jsfiddle.net/upmuvk6t/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you change from `display: table-cell` to `display: inline-block` the heights will vary

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `display` of `.navigationtab` from `table-cell` to `inline-block`
as table-cell is constrained to have height of its parent (table)

```
.navigationtab {
  vertical-align: top; /* aligns to top */
  display: inline-block; /* displays side by side */
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/upmuvk6t/2/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the above as a menus add **float:left;** & **display:inline-block** to **.navigationtab** class and remove **display:table-cell** as below

```
.navigationtab {
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family: 'Baloo Tamma', cursive;
    float:left 
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #00ace6;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```